# Why can't I use gem install command (linux/ ruby / rails)?

Tags: rubygems

I'm having problems when issuing 'gem' command. I have both rubygems1.8 and rubygems1.9. My rails version is rails-2.3.3. My ruby ruby 1.8.7. And I'm on Linux.

My problem is that I can't issue

```
gem install <gem name>
```

Instead I have to give:

```
gem1.8 install <gem name>
```

Can anyone tell me why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a symbolic link to gem1.8

> ```
> ln /usr/bin/gem1.8 /usr/bin/gem
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Because you installed two different versions and they can't both be named "gem."